# Can WCF Service use the same AD FS 2.0 endpoint as Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, adfs2.0, adfs

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that is claims aware and is using AD FS 2.0 STS to authenticate users. Now I want to make WCF services in this application also claims aware.

Can I use the same ADFS endpoint for the services or should I create new one for each service or one for all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - there are separate endpoints for web services.

Look in ADFS under Services / Endpoints. Note that not all are enabled by default.

I blogged about this - [ADFS : WCF web service](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/adfs-wcf-web-service.html)

Comment: I upvoted the answer, however, there seems to be something wrong with your blog entry. Either some images are missing or some parts of the text.

Comment: You mean the spaces between the paragraphs? I find when I use Blooger with Windows Live Writer, the first time it's OK but if I update, that's what happens. So it's back to vanilla Blogger for me!

Comment: No, I mean "with followng syntax" and nothing follows.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get back to this on Monday or during weekend. What about second part of the question? Should I create one endpoint per service or can I use one for all services?

Comment: Ah - I see - yes something's definitely missing there!